# PHP / AJAX | No response or changes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i got a problem with my ajax update.
My current code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.application_invite').click(function(){
            var $invite_steamid = $steamid;

            $.ajax({
                url:"application.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{invite_steamid:invite_steamid},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#application_inbox').html(data);
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

To make the request i put 'application_invite' as class for the element 'li':

```
<li class="application_invite">
     <a class="cursor">
         <i class="fa fa fa-folder- open"></i> 
             Eingeladen
         <span class="label label-primary pull-right"><? =$countInvitedApplys?></span>
     </a>
</li>
```

The file 'application.php' is in the same folder and put 'application_inbox' as id for the .

```
<div class="row" id="application_inbox">
```

But the file application.php doesnt get called at all, but i absolutely don't know why.
I hope someone can help me

Comment: `invite_steamid` != `$invite_steamid` typo in question

Comment: I also do not see `$steamid` defined any where.

Comment: " i absolutely don't know why."...then do some debugging. Check your browser's developer tools - Console and Network sections specifically - to see what happened to your request. As others have said, you have a mismatch in your variable names. So perhaps the call _is_ being made, but with the wrong values. Or perhaps there's a crash. You need to do some proper investigation.

Comment: @Taplar $steamid is getting defined above $steamid = $_SESSION['steamid'];

Comment: That looks like PHP logic.  PHP and javascript do not run at the same time.  You need to include more scope to your question, because it now sounds like you potentially have bigger issues.

Comment: Put the data:{'invite_steamid':invite_steamid} instead of data:{invite_steamid:invite_steamid} you are forget to add single quotation on invite_steamid data

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan underscore is a valid character for object keys.  Quotes are unnecessary in this case.  You can verify this by opening your browser console and just typing `{ a_b: 'c' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself .. it was just a dumb mistake i made^^

The first thing i changed was this

```
var $invite_steamid = $steamid;
    ^
```

to:

```
var invite_steamid = <?=$steamid?>;
                      ^         ^
```

After changing that two things, it worked^^

Thanks to Taplar and ADyson, your comments helped me to solve it.